# Is a downsampled ARMA process also an ARMA process?

Tags: time-series, stationary-processes

I have an $\operatorname{ARMA}(p,q)$ process $X_n$, defined say by
$$
\varphi(L)X_n=\vartheta(L)\varepsilon_n.
$$
with i.i.d. Gaussian innovation terms $\varepsilon_n$.

I can observe this process only at a reduced frequency, once every $k$ time steps. That means that I observe the process $Y_m=X_{km}$ for some integer $k>1$.

**My Questions**

- Is the process $Y_m$ also representable as an ARMA process? Or does it belong to some other larger class of stochastic processes?
- If $Y_m$ is effectively an ARMA process, is there an explicit procedure to compute its coefficients?

**Special cases**

The question has an affirmative answer in some special cases:

- If $X_n$ is an $\operatorname{AR}(1)$ process coefficient $\varphi$, then $Y_m$ is also an $\operatorname{AR}(1)$ process with coefficient $\varphi^k$ and innovation terms $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\varphi^{k-i}\varepsilon_{km-i+1}$.
- If $X_t$ is a continuous Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process and $Y_m$ is a sampling of $X_t$ at regular intervals, then $Y_m$ is an $\operatorname{AR}(1)$ process.
- If $X_n$ is an $\operatorname{MA}(q)$ process with $q\leq k$ then $Y_m$ is a white noise process.

PS. If it may be useful, the process $X_n$ can be assumed to be weakly or strongly stationary.

Comment: Well, you can definitely do it as a vector ARMA, but I don't think you can do $Y_m$ with just a single 1-D whitenoise in the MA(infinity) representation.

Comment: The best I could do is writing it as $$Y_m=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\vartheta^{(i)}(L)}{\varphi^{(i)}(L)}\varepsilon^{(i)}_m,$$ where the $\varepsilon^{(i)}$ are lagged combinations of the original $\varepsilon$.
I was hoping to find a more explicit form.

Comment: Asking to reopen the question. The question looks very natural to me and emerged in a real-world problem: if I can observe only a regular subsample of an ARMA process, can I still model my observations as ARMA or should I consider a larger class of stochastic processes? I have edited the question with this motivation and added some simple special cases where the answer is affirmative.

Comment: In real-world I don't think you know the data comes from an ARMA process so I think people just wing it until a parsimonious fit is found.

Comment: Yes, I have provided an answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/526386/77222